# Detailed information about the Habo church

Tags: sweden, architecture, photography, religion, jonkoping

A friend of mine is currently studying in Skövde, Sweden. The weekend after this one he is going to Jönköping for a short vacation. I was helping him to find some information about Jönköping but we couldn't find any more detail about the habo church. We are particularly interested if it is necessary to pay a fee to visit it and since he is a passionate photographer: What is the best day time to take pictures of this church? This means, during which time of day the sun isn't behind the church?

Comment: random fact: jönköping is called the "jerusalem of sweden" due to the large number of pentecostals in the area.

Comment: @KateGregory I'd consider putting that as an answer, as it's valuable info for a photographer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Svenska kyrkan](http://www.svenskakyrkan.se/default.aspx?id=654452) (the main Lutheran church of Sweden) says that the church is open Monday to Friday and Sundays between 10 and 16 this time of year. It also says that you can get in touch with Daniel Carlsson to get a guided tour. His phone numbers are 036-420 93 and 0701-74 30 45.

(Google search tips when looking for church information: search for - in this case - "Habo Kyrka" and look for links from svenskakyrkan.se.)

Comment: [Why shouldn't we use the word 'here' in a textlink](http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/12100/why-shouldnt-we-use-the-word-here-in-a-textlink) (applies to "this" too)

Comment: lol - actually thought about that when I wrote it. Do you like the edit better? (It is not always easy to do it right for us non-native english speakers. But good to get feedback!)

Comment: Yes it's really nice now. Sorry I've been chasing everybody about "here" and "this" and "this page" links. It improves our readability and Google-ability to fix them like you have so thank you (-:

Answer (score 7):

Use Bing Maps or Google maps to find the church ("Habo Church" got very close on Bing Maps), switch to photo view to confirm the building, and you can see the driveway along with a compass rose. (The Wikipedia page has a photo that shows you the colour of the roof and discusses the layout of the building itself.) Seems like the sun will be behind the building in the morning, making afternoon better for pictures.